# How to forecast few periods ahead,a univariate timeseries using support vector regression

Tags: r, svm, forecasting

I have the following data:

```
head(df)

pce        pop        psavert    uempmed    unemploy
507.8      198712     9.8        4.5        2944
510.9      198911     9.8        4.7        2945
516.7      199113     9.8        4.6        2958
513.3      199311     9.8        4.9        3143
518.5      199498     9.8        4.7        3066
```

I am trying to use SVM - regression to fit the data like this

```
svmRbftune <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert + uempmed,
                    data = EconomicsTrain, method = "svmRadial",
                    tunelength = 14, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

svmRbfPredict <- predict(svmRbftune, EconomicsTest)
```

What i would like is to forecast say 3 periods ahead.....i am stuck as to how i can do that..literature is quite vague regarding it....

Answer (score 0):

You need new feature values to make predictions.

For example:

```
svmRbftune <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert + uempmed,
                data = head(EconomicsTrain,-3), method = "svmRadial",
                tunelength = 14, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

svmRbfPredict <- predict(svmRbftune, tail(EconomicsTest,3))
```

Comment: Thnx for responding.....actually what i am looking for is a forecast...beyond the data .....using the SVR model .....this is a timeseries data and i am trying to understand how SVR can be used to forecast  k periods ahead...as we do in arima forecasting